# PL/SQL Initiate a multi-dimensional array INDEX BY VARCHAR2

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following code which works just fine in building a 2D array indexed by `VARCHAR2`.  But I have a question about how I would instantiate the top-level array with an "empty" second level array.  (See the comments in the code.)

The only way I've found to instantiate the initial array (inside the `Add()` procedure) is to declare a dummy variable (which is itself an empty array), and assign it to the top-level array:

```sql
DECLARE

   TYPE pt_array  IS TABLE OF number   INDEX BY VARCHAR2(25);
   TYPE prj_array IS TABLE OF pt_array INDEX BY VARCHAR2(25);

   pt_array_ pt_array;
   pj_array_ prj_array;

   PROCEDURE Add (
      act_  IN VARCHAR2,
      pt_   IN VARCHAR2,
      val_  IN NUMBER )
   IS
      dummy_empty_array pt_array; -- initiate a dummy variable
   BEGIN
      IF not pj_array_.EXISTS(act_) THEN
         pj_array_(act_) := dummy_empty_array; -- can I initiate here without having to declare a variable?
      END IF;
      IF not pj_array_(act_).EXISTS(pt_) THEN
         pj_array_(act_)(pt_) := val_;
      END IF;
   END Add;

BEGIN
   Add ('A', '123', 1);
   Add ('A', '456', 1);
   Add ('B', '456', 1);
END;
```

Most languages offer the ability to assign an anonymous array when required (i.e. without having to define an intermittent variable).  For example, in Javascript you'd just do `x = [];`.  But I haven't found a way to do this in PL/SQL.

I've tried various different syntaxes, one obvious example being the following (which errors at compile time with "no function with name 'PT_ARRAY' exists"):

```sql
    pj_array_(act_) := pt_array();
```

Also, the concept of using keyword `EXTEND` doesn't apply if you're declaring you array/tables with an `INDEX BY` clause.

So my question is whether it's possible to write this code (i.e. to initiate the empty array) without the dummy variable?

Comment: You are correct, lack of a useful constructor for index-by tables (and records) is a known 'issue' and support was added in 19c (edit: actually 18c). Prior to that I believe CAST (NULL AS type_name) would be equivalent, e.g. pj_array_ (act_) := CAST (NULL AS pt_array) should work in your case and is more straightforward than having to declare a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for the syntax you want (`pj_array_(act_) := pt_array();`) was added in Oracle Database 18c:

```
DECLARE

   TYPE pt_array  IS TABLE OF number   INDEX BY VARCHAR2(25);
   TYPE prj_array IS TABLE OF pt_array INDEX BY VARCHAR2(25);

   pt_array_ pt_array;
   pj_array_ prj_array;

   PROCEDURE Add (
      act_  IN VARCHAR2,
      pt_   IN VARCHAR2,
      val_  IN NUMBER )
   IS
   BEGIN
      IF not pj_array_.EXISTS(act_) THEN
         pj_array_(act_) := pt_array();
      END IF;
      IF not pj_array_(act_).EXISTS(pt_) THEN
         pj_array_(act_)(pt_) := val_;
      END IF;
   END Add;

BEGIN
   Add ('A', '123', 1);
   Add ('A', '456', 2);
   Add ('B', '456', 3);

   dbms_output.put_line ( pj_array_ ('A')('123') );
   dbms_output.put_line ( pj_array_ ('A')('456') );
   dbms_output.put_line ( pj_array_ ('B')('456') );
END;
/
1
2
3
```

Comment: Yes, I had to build my solution in Oracle 12c, so I didn't provide enough information in the original question.  Nevertheless, this is the [or "a"] correct answer.